# how to add fields to a bigquery table when loading new data

Tags: google-bigquery

Using the example below:

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# dataset_id = 'my_dataset'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
]
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
# The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, dataset_ref.table("us_states"), job_config=job_config
)  # API request
print("Starting job {}".format(load_job.job_id))

load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
print("Job finished.")

destination_table = client.get_table(dataset_ref.table("us_states"))
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

how do I add a filename, and a current_date field to this?  is it possible during creation? or do I have to wait until the table is made and do it there somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Reading directly from a CSV that does not contain these fields, I'm not sure. An alternative approach could be to read the CSV into a dataframe, then add these extra columns and write the dataframe into BigQuery, this way you'd have additional control over the fields that you choose to add.

Comment: Another approach: leave said CSV file GCS and read it as an external source/table and materialize it to a native table. When you're reading it in, use the `_FILE_NAME` pseudo column to get the filename and `CURRENT_DATE()` for the other.  Another: load it, wait and then hit it with some SQL afterwards, cross-joining it with the details you want. Finally, use Cloud Dataflow to read the file, add your columns and write to BigQuery.

Comment: @Ben P could you post you comment as an answer for the benefit of the community?

Answer (score 0):

Reading directly from a CSV that does not contain these fields, I'm not sure this can be done.

However, an alternative approach could be to read the CSV into a dataframe, then add these extra columns and write the dataframe into BigQuery, this way you'd have additional control over the fields that you choose to add.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  This needs to happen.  ;).  IMaybe I"ll put in a feature request.